# mod_rewrite problems when rewriting two variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website url like this: 
`/team.php?name=any-team-name&tid=200`

Want to overwrite to `/teams/any-team-name/200/`

by using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^teams/([A-Za-z]+)/(0-9]+)/? team.php?name=$1&tid=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Getting this result in browser:
The requested URL `/teams/any-team-name/200/` was not found on this server.

Additionally, I'll have to use some unrewritten variables like

```
/teams/any-team-name/200/&viewall=1&filter=1&home=1&away=1#history
```

Will `[QSA,L]` be enough to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^team/([A-Za-z\-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\&\=_]+)/? /team.php?name=$1&tid=$2$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^team/([A-Za-z\-_]+)/([0-9]+)/? /team.php?name=$1&tid=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Also in your example above you had an error, you were missing a `[` from `(0-9]+)`

Comment: Ty, not ok. after calling team/name/200/ got 404, maybe sth wrong with my server configuration?

Comment: Np, feel free to make it as answered so other people who have a question like you, can see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^teams/([A-Za-z\-_]+)/([0-9]+)/? team.php?name=$1&tid=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Use this pattern on team name `[A-Za-z\-_]`, you didn't include the `-` in your pattern `[A-Za-z]`. Actually you have hyphens `-` in your url.

Comment: No this brings the same not found page. Also try this RewriteRule ^teams/(.*)/*(.*)/*$ team.php?&tid=$1&name=$2 [NC,QSA,L] and this opens the page but passes only Array
(
    [tid] => 200
    [name] => 
) when /teams/200/any-name/